# How to map inherited data objects to corresponding view models without losing their type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Say I have some classes created using Entity Framework which use inheritance. For example:

```
namespace MyEntities
{
    Person
    Employee : Person
    Customer : Person
    WebCustomer : Customer
}
```

And I also have the same class names in another namespace used as the basis of view models:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    Person
    Employee : Person
    Customer : Person
    WebCustomer : Customer
}
```

I can then do fun things like using a generic method to create a viewmodel of a known type:

```
public T Make<T>(Entities.Person entity) where T : ViewModels.Person, new()
{
    T model = (T)new T().InjectFrom(entity);
    return model;
}
```

But what I can't figure out how to do is make a model of the correct type in the case that I don't know the type in advance - I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
ViewModels.Person person = GetPersonById(24);
```

And have that person object be of one of the underlying types - say a WebCustomer.

This would allow me to use the EditorFor and DisplayFor templates in MVC.net to display the right controls for the right types of Person, even when just grabbing one by Id.

I can use the Editor and Display templates if I allow the Entities to bubble up to the website, but if I want to have mapping logic along the way I can't seem to get the type information correct.

I suppose what's needed is a method like:

```
ViewModels.Person person Get(MyEntities entity)
{
// ??
}
```

Where the person object returned is mapped by name and cast to the correct underlying type. Is there a way to achieve this behavior? Or is there better way to handle passing inherited structures through a model mapper that I should be doing instead?

Comment: How would you expect to retrieve any potential specific-type model by only Id?  You'd need to either constrain your controllers by type OR you'd have to include additional metadata to know what type the id should be correlated with.

Comment: @DavidL - I'd expect to use the TPT inheritance structure to let the Entity Framework figure it out by Id - this works perfectly well if I use the entity layer in the web UI. I can pass an Id back and get EF to pass me back a correctly typed object which the DisplayFor in MVC correctly serves up the appropriate view - the only thing I don't like about it is that it requires the Web UI to reference the Entity Framework types

Comment: But you are breaking the TPT inheritance structure.  So that argument no longer holds,  hence my point that you'd need additional metadata.  An Id once you've broken the inheritance chain is no longer sufficient.  And for the record, I agree.  You shouldn't be exposing EF types to your web layer.

Comment: @DavidL - I see what you mean. I hoping to find a way to use the type provided by EF as the meta-data I need to create the View Model and hence avoid passing that meta-data down. If EF can create an entity object of the right class using TPT and I know my view model classes have the exact same name, then I theoretically have all the information I need, right? (Although I understand that still doesn't mean it's possible in practice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a generic factory. Take the following code for example:

```
public static PersonViewModelFactory
{
    public static TViewModel CreateFrom<TViewModel>(TEntity entity)
        where TViewModel : PersonViewModel, new()
    {
        return new TViewModel { // map properties from Person }
    }
}
```

Then, to use this you just do:

```
var viewModel = PersonViewModelFactory.CreateFrom<CustomerViewModel>(person);
```

Then, `viewModel` will be typed as `CustomerViewModel`. However, it's important to realize that you're playing to a least common denominator here, so even though you're returning a `CustomerViewModel`, the only properties you can utilize are properties that exist on `Person`, not `Customer`. The only way you could access `Customer` properties would be either overload the method to take an instance of `Customer` as a param or make the entity param generic as well. However, if both are generic, then they'll both need to implement a common interface. That way you can constrain the type param to the interface and access the properties that interface defines.

Long and short, creating a truly generic type mapper is a pain. Either you accept the limitations of the approaches I mention, or just use an existing library for this type of thing, like AutoMapper. After all, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments, yes, you are correct.  If you have the exact name, you COULD substitute namespacing information and create an instance with `Activator`, provided that your namespacing is always consistent.

```
MyEntities entity
ViewModels.Person person = Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType("ViewModels" + "." + entity.GetType().Name));
```

You could then create dynamic mappings or use a library like EmitMapper to map between your objects.

Keep in mind that there are always some performance penalties to these types of approaches.  That said, if it is a small enough margin that you are comfortable with it, it will give you the dynamic approach that you are looking for.